# ASP.NET v2 - RadGridView

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

I have a grid that I need to add columns to dynamically (programatically).

I have been browsing Telerik forums as well as Google and im not able to find anything. Decompiling GridTemplateColumn shows that there should be ItemTemplate property however my VS throws an error.

```
Dim col As GridColumn = New GridButtonColumn()
col.UniqueName = stockLocation("LocationID").ToString()
col.HeaderText = stockLocation("Name").ToString()
col.ItemTemplate = ERROR HERE
rgGridCombinations.Columns.Add(col)
```

I'm trying to create a column that will look like following ASPX code.

```
<radg:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Stock" UniqueName="Stock" Visible="true" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbStock" runat="server" Width="100%" />
</ItemTemplate>
</radg:GridTemplateColumn>
```

How would I create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `GridColumn` does not have `ItemTemplate` property

2) You were assigning `GridButtonColumn`. Use `GridTemplateColumn` instead

Try this

```
Dim col = As New GridTemplateColumn()
col.UniqueName = "Stock"
col.HeaderText = "Stock"
col.ItemTemplate = <something here>  'should be an ITemplate

rgGridCombinations.Columns.Add(col)
```

For more information on [how to create template, check here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-templates-adding.html)

Comment: My visual studio doesn't recognize ItemTemplate property inside the column.

Comment: why do you have to go this way and not use markup? From the link I posted, it's not straight forward. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a grid that currently uses ColumnTemplates with TextBoxes inside it (everything is coded in markup). However, new feature request came in that requires dynamic column generation (based on rows from database). I'm familiar with WPF and Silverlight not so much with ASP.NET (I'm used to bindings, however in this grid someone just pulls each text box in each cell and fills it out with data when grid loads). Therefore I need to create dynamic columns with text boxes, then when save is clicked to pick them up and save it. Sounds simple.

Comment: I managed to get it around it by having one column with a place holder inside it, however I was unable to find a solution.

Comment: I wish to help but I already spent time on it and it's like it's not the best option. can you describe more... and how far have you gone? There may be a better approach if I understand your task